# How does fold works for empty list?

Tags: haskell, fold

When we fold a list with one or more elements inside as done below:

```
foldr (+) 0 [1,2,3]
```

> We get:
>
> foldr (+) 0 (1 : 2 : 3 : [])
>
> foldr (+)   1 + (2 +(3 + 0)) // 6

Now when the list is empty:

```
 foldr (+) 0 []
```

> Result: foldr (+) 0 ([])

Since (+) is binary operator, it needs two arguments to complete but here we end up `(+) 0`. How does it result in 0 and not throwing error of partially applied function.

Comment: `(+0)` is not the same as `foldr (+) 0 []`

Comment: You can think of `foldr f z xs` as “replacing” all the `:` in `xs` with `f` and the `[]` (if present) with `z`. So `foldr (+) 0 []` replaces `[]` with `0`, and there are no `:` to replace, so the `+` is never used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**: you get the **initial value `z`**.

If you give `foldl` or `foldr` an empty list, then it returns the **initial** value. [`foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr) works like:

> ```
> foldr f z [x1, x2, ..., xn] == x1 `f` (x2 `f` ... (xn `f` z)...)
> ```

So since there are no `x1`, ..., `xn` the function is never applied, and `z` is returned.

We can also inspect the [source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#foldr):

> ```
> foldr            :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
> -- foldr _ z []     =  z
> -- foldr f z (x:xs) =  f x (foldr f z xs)
> {-# INLINE [0] foldr #-}
> -- Inline only in the final stage, after the foldr/cons rule has had a chance
> -- Also note that we inline it when it has *two* parameters, which are the
> -- ones we are keen about specialising!
> foldr k z = go
>           where
>             go []     = z
>             go (y:ys) = y `k` go ys
> ```

So if we give `foldr` an empty list, then `go` will immediately work on that empty list, and return `z`, the initial value.

A cleaner syntax (and a bit less efficient, as is written in the comment of the function) would thus be:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr _ z [] = z
foldr f z (x:xs) = f x (foldr f z xs)
```

Note that - depending on the implementation of `f` - it is possible to `foldr` on infinite lists: if at some point `f` only looks at the initial value, and then returns a value, then the recursive part can be dropped.